# take a photo with webcam and upload to server laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, image, form-data

I´m traying to get my webcam, take a photo and upload to my filesystem. My problem it´s that my form data it´s empty and i don´t know where it´s my problem. Attach my code and my blade.

this it´s my html:

```
<div class="form-group">
                            <label for="videoSelect">Camera</label>
                            <div class="camera">
                                <select id="videoSelect" class="custom-select"></select>
                                <button id="startCameraButton" class="btn btn-success">Start Camera</button>
                                <video id="video">Video stream not available.</video>
                                <button id="takePictureButton" class="btn btn-info d-none">Take photo</button>
                            </div>
                                
                            <canvas class="d-none" id="canvas" name="fileName"></canvas>
                        </div>
```

And this it´s my javascript:

```
<script>
                document.getElementById("editProfile").addEventListener("click", function(event){
                    event.preventDefault()
                });

                var width = 320;
                var height = 0;
                var streaming = false;
                var localstream = null;

                startCameraButton.onclick = start;
                takePictureButton.onclick = takepicture;

                navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
                        .then(gotDevices)
                        .catch(function (err) {
                            console.log("An error occured while getting device list! " + err);
                        });

                function gotDevices(deviceInfos) {
                    while (videoSelect.firstChild) {
                        videoSelect.removeChild(videoSelect.firstChild);
                    }

                    for (var i = 0; i !== deviceInfos.length; ++i) {
                        var deviceInfo = deviceInfos[i];
                        var option = document.createElement('option');
                        option.value = deviceInfo.deviceId;
                        if (deviceInfo.kind === 'videoinput') {
                            option.text = deviceInfo.label || 'Camera ' + (videoSelect.length + 1);
                            videoSelect.appendChild(option);
                        }
                    }
                }

                function start() {
                    takePictureButton.classList.remove("d-none")
                    stopVideo();
                    clearphoto();
                    var videoSource = videoSelect.value;
                    var constraints = {
                        audio: false,
                        video: {deviceId: videoSource ? {exact: videoSource} : undefined}
                    };
                    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).
                            then(gotStream).then(gotDevices).catch(handleError);
                }



                function gotStream(stream) {
                    localstream = stream;
                    video.srcObject = stream;
                    video.play();
                    // Refresh button list in case labels have become available
                    return navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
                }

                function handleError(error) {
                    console.log('navigator.getUserMedia error: ', error);
                }

                video.addEventListener('canplay', function (ev) {
                    if (!streaming) {
                        height = video.videoHeight / (video.videoWidth / width);
                        video.setAttribute('width', width);
                        video.setAttribute('height', height);
                        canvas.setAttribute('width', width);
                        canvas.setAttribute('height', height);

                        streaming = true;
                    }
                }, false);

                clearphoto();

                function clearphoto() {
                    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                    context.fillStyle = "#AAA";
                    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                }

                function takepicture() {
                    canvas.classList.remove("d-none")
                    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                    if (width && height) {
                        canvas.width = width;
                        canvas.height = height;
                        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);

                        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.95);
                        if (dataURL && dataURL != "data:,") {
                            var fileName = generateImageName();
                            fileName = fileName;
                            uploadimage(dataURL, fileName);
                        } else {
                            console.log("Image not available");
                        }
                    } else {
                        clearphoto();
                    }
                }

                function generateImageName() {
                    var today = new Date();
                    var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
                    var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
                    var dateTime = date+'_'+time;

                    let name = document.getElementById("inputName").value;

                    return name+"_"+dateTime+ ".jpg";
                }

                function uploadimage(dataurl, filename) {
                    let image = new Image();
                    image.src = dataurl;

                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.onload = function () {
                        if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
                            console.log('¡Éxito!', xhr.response);
                        }else{
                            console.log('Error en la petición!');
                        }
                    }
                    xhr.open('POST', "{{ route('patients.profileImage') }}");
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", "{{ csrf_token() }}");
                    var formData = new FormData();
                    formData.append("image", image.src);
                    formData.append("fileName", filename);

                    //xhr.send(formData);
                }

                function stopVideo() {
                    if (localstream) {
                        localstream.getTracks().forEach(function (track) {
                            track.stop();
                            localstream = null;
                        });
                    }
                }
            </script>
```

My controller:

```
function profileImage(Request $request)
    {
        $img = $request->get('image');
        $imgTran1 = str_replace('data:image/jpg;base64,', '', $img);
        $imgTran2 = str_replace(' ', '+', $imgTran1);
        $data = base64_decode($imgTran2);

        \Storage::disk('public')->move($img, $data);
    }
```

My problem it´s that form data in javascript it´s empty, i don´t know why... I don´t see my error.

Thans for read me and sorry for my bad english

Comment: How is this a laravel problem if the form-data is empty?

Comment: @geertjanknapen not it´s problem laravel, my problem i think that it´s in javascript that not send my form data... I set tag laravel because i´m using this framework to back-end..

Comment: In your question, you say the Javascript form-data is empty, so it will not even reach the Laravel controller if there is no data to pass..